# Fan is always on on my asus rog

Tags: asus, fan

I have an Asus Rog-GL553Vd laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. However, the fan is always on. It's  really loud and  it's annoying. My CPU usage is around 2-5%. 
Please someone do me a favor to solve this problem ..

Comment: Favor granted: welcome to the fun filled adventure of linux, take apart your computer and clean the dust out of the heat sink, dust is clogging the heat so it can't escape causing your fan to try to put out a fire, but it can't with a wall in the way

Comment: But when i use windows i donot face that problem..

Comment: Have you used: top to determine what processes are using near 100 percent to keep the fan high, most common problems are a minconfigured USB port, start unplugging stuff to see when it drops or webcontent without acceleration enabled on your browser.

Comment: I face that problem even when i don't use any app...

Comment: can we see the output of: watch "ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 10"

Comment: in ubuntu 18.10 fan speed is normal but when i click to shutdown display freezes and then there is nothing to do without force shutdown ...

Comment: hello hello moto here is the output :
https://imgur.com/a/CyW6nQj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not installed any of the power management services in Ubuntu, you may find these to be helpful:

First, install Tlp, Thermald, and Lmsensors to create power sensing and management. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt install tlp thermald
sudo apt install --install-suggests lm-sensors psensor
```

There are configuration files for Tlp located in /etc/default/tlp which you can customize to fit your needs. You can issue `sudo tlp start` to start the process, but I would reboot.

Secondly, there are a set of utilities to set the fan speeds for various sensed temperatures. The following is quoted from https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1165469-control-fan-speeds-lm_sensors-isnt-working/?tab=comments#comment-595825859

> ```
> sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
> sudo sensors-detect
> ```
>
> just follow the prompts. Add the recommended lines to /etc/modules.
>
> Now, if you don't want to reboot, you'll have to manually activate the
>   modules.
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe module1 module2
> ```
>
> where module1 etc. = the module names provided from sensors-detect.
>
> Next, you need to create your fancontrol file. The easiest way is to
>   run pwmconfig.
>
> ```
> sudo pwmconfig
> ```
>
> and work your way through the instructions there.
>
> Finally, run sensors -s to make your fan configuration take effect.
>
> ```
> sudo sensors -s
> ```
>
> Now, you can check your temps.
>
> ```
> sensors
> ```
>
> Now to run fan control, type:
>
> ```
> sudo /usr/sbin/fancontrol &
> ```
>
> A nice way to visually inspect temps is with gkrellm. To get it:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gkrellm
> ```

Comment: pwmconfig gives me "There are no PWM outputs"

Comment: And the sensors command gives me this "cpu_fan:        0 RPM"

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this one and it helps a bit. [LMT](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/laptop-mode-tools-1-67-ubuntu-14-04/)

> Laptop Mode Tools controls the “laptop mode” feature of the Linux kernel. It saves power by spinning down hard drives, and in addition, it can be configured to tweak all sorts of other power-related things.

You have to remore TLP if you count on using this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt update
sudo apt install laptop-mode-tools
```

You can use the .deb packages directly from [this link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/l/laptop-mode-tools/)

You then lunch it this this command and restart :

```
gksu lmt-config-gui
```

Comment: O my god this is working...Thanx man..